# -9999 as missing value with numpy.genfromtxt()

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

Lets say I have a dumb text file with the contents:

```
Year    Recon   Observed
1505    162.38        23      
1506     46.14     -9999      
1507    147.49     -9999
```

`-9999` is used to denote a missing value (don't ask).

So, I should be able to read this into a Numpy array with:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.genfromtxt("file.txt", dtype = None, names = True, missing_values = -9999)
```

And have all my little `-9999`s turn into numpy.nan. But, I get:

```
>>> x
array([(1409, 112.38, 23), (1410, 56.14, -9999), (1411, 145.49, -9999)], 
  dtype=[('Year', '<i8'), ('Recon', '<f8'), ('Observed', '<i8')])
```

... That's not right...

Am I missing something?

Comment: why is -9999 used to denote a missing value? :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, you're not doing anything wrong. Using the `missing_values` argument indeed tells `np.genfromtxt` that the corresponding values should be flagged as "missing/invalid". The problem is that dealing with missing values is only supported if you use the `usemask=True` argument (I probably should have made that clearer in the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html), my bad).

With `usemask=True`, the output is a masked array. You can transform it into a regular `ndarray` with the missing values replaced by `np.nan` with the method `.filled(np.nan)`.

Be careful, though:  if you have column that was detected as having a `int` dtype and you try to fill its missing values with `np.nan`, you won't get what you expect (`np.nan` is only supported for float columns).

Comment: unfortunately, nearly 10 years later, I still needed to come here ;-) Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

Trying:

```
>>> x = np.genfromtxt("file.txt",names = True, missing_values = "-9999", dtype=None)
>>> x
array([(1505, 162.38, 23), (1506, 46.14, -9999), (1507, 147.49, -9999)], 
      dtype=[('Year', '<i8'), ('Recon', '<f8'), ('Observed', '<i8')])
```

does not give the correct answer. So just making it a string doesn't help. However, if an additional flag, `usemask=True` is added, you get:

```
>>> x = np.genfromtxt("file.txt",names = True, missing_values = -9999, dtype=None, usemask=True)
>>> x
masked_array(data = [(1505, 162.38, 23) (1506, 46.14, --) (1507, 147.49, --)],
             mask = [(False, False, False) (False, False, True) (False, False, True)],
       fill_value = (999999, 1e+20, 999999),
            dtype = [('Year', '<i8'), ('Recon', '<f8'), ('Observed', '<i8')])
```

which gives what you want in a MaskedArray, which may be useable for you anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The [numpy documentation at SciPy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) suggests that the missing_value should be a string to work the way you want.  A straight numeric value seems to be interpreted as a column index.